# Spark standalone failed to load file

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have spark 2.3.1 installed on an HPC cluster in the "standalone" mode (no HDFS). I used pySpark and tried to do simple RDD operation (these are in pyspark):

```
rdd = sc.textFile("/scratch-lustre/wpurwant/_log-20181107-pyspark.log")
rdd.count()
```

This Spark program used to work; I didn't do anything to change the software. And for sure I know that the file referenced above did exist. I can `ls` and `cat` it.

I am puzzled as to why suddenly the commands above produced this error (earlier part removed):

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/scratch-lustre/wpurwant/_log-20181107-pyspark.log
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: well the error shows it doesnt exist. try `ls /scratch-lustre/wpurwant/_log-20181107-pyspark.log` . and show its output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. Spark don't like filenames that starts with an underscore! Renaming the file to not start with an underscore works!